# issue with SELECT inside WHERE clause postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a table using these commands:

```
SELECT
    data_req,
    count(servico) as qtdeServico,
    count(metodo) as qtdeMetodo,
    consumerid,
    metodo,
    status_metodo,
    servico,
    sum(tempo_req)
INTO
    consolidado
FROM 
    requisicoes AS r
WHERE 
    r.data_req > SELECT MAX(c.data_req) FROM consolidado c  
GROUP BY 
    data_req, consumerid, metodo, status_metodo, servico;
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error at the select clause inside where. I'm using postgres.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't the subquery in the where clause be wrapped in brackets?

Comment: The query doesn't make sense.  You seem to be trying to create a table called `consolidado` while also selecting from that same table.  Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has numerous idiosyncrasies.  The following would be more correct syntax:

```
create table consolidado as 
    select data_req, count(servico) as qtdeServico, count(metodo) as qtdeMetodo,
           consumerid, metodo, status_metodo, servico,
           sum(tempo_req) as sum_tempo_req
    from requisicoes r
    where r.data_req > (select max(c.data_req) from consolidado c) 
    group by data_req, consumerid, metodo, status_metodo, servico;
```

This fixes the following errors:

- Postgres recommends `CREATE TABLE AS` over `SELECT INTO` (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156105/2639)).
- All columns should be named when creating a table.
- You need parens around the subquery.

However, the query doesn't make sense.  It is creating a table called `consolidado` and also reading from the table.  That is logically troublesome.  In addition, `qtMetodo` and `qtdeServico` will generally have the same values -- they are in the `GROUP BY` columns meaning that they are separated by groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the SELECT sentence with "(....)":

```
SELECT
    data_req,
    count(servico) as qtdeServico,
    count(metodo) as qtdeMetodo,
    consumerid,
    metodo,
    status_metodo,
    servico,
    sum(tempo_req)
    into consolidado
    FROM requisicoes as r
    WHERE 
    r.data_req > (select max(c.data_req) from consolidado c  
    GROUP BY data_req, consumerid, metodo, status_metodo, servico);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `consolidado` already exists.. You will need to use `INSERT INTO ()... SELECT` syntax.  The subquery should be inside parentheses as well:

```
INSERT INTO consolidado (data_req, qtdeServico.. rest of cols)
SELECT
    data_req,
    count(servico) as qtdeServico,
    count(metodo) as qtdeMetodo,
    consumerid,
    metodo,
    status_metodo,
    servico,
    sum(tempo_req)
FROM requisicoes as r
WHERE r.data_req > (select max(c.data_req) from consolidado c)
GROUP BY data_req, consumerid, metodo, status_metodo, servico;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other's points about [CREATE TABLE AS vs SELECT INTO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156105/2639), I would *highly* suggest you checkout [`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) which sounds like more of what you want..